# Position of "here" in a sentence

Tags: sentence, word-position

**Background** In my thesis I have to write without 1st person. On the other hand I sometimes have to explain how I have chosen some parameters or how I have realized some implementation etc. (which in a paper I would write in 1st person of course).

My solution is very often to write "*in this work*" or passive voice or whatsoever. It also stands to reason to use the word "*here*" more often. However, in the most cases it sounds awkward and I am unsure where to position it.

**Questions** At which position of the sentence I should position the word "here"? Which of the following versions should be preferred:

```
Version 1: A has to be transformed to B, which here is done by a rotation R.
Version 2: A has to be transformed to B, which is done by a rotation R here.
```

Or should I 100%ly avoid the word "*here*" in scientific context?

**My impression** Version 2 sounds more natural to me. On the other hand the "*here*" feels so like a little bit "too much". This becomes even worse for longer sentences. In version 1 "*here*" better fits into the sentence and puts the emphasis where I like it. Unfortunately, it sounds grammatically awkward to me.

Comment: Could you say, for example "In this case, a rotation R transforms A to B"? Or is it crucial to include the general rule "A has to be transformed to B" in some form? The range of wording options you have at your disposal depends in large measure to how rigidly you must present certain component phrases in your work.

Comment: *A has to be transformed to B, which is done by a rotation R **here.*** (correct) — *A has to be transformed to B, which \*here is done by a rotation R .* (sounds odd) — *A has to be transformed to B, which is **here** done by a rotation R.* (probably possible) — *A has to be transformed to B, which is done **here** by a rotation R.* (possible)

Answer (score -1):

It is not necessary, but you could drop the use of 'here' altogether.

> A was transformed to B by rotation R.

or

> Rotation R was used to transform A to B.

With more context I'd suggest a preference.  For example if you intend to talk about rotation R in the next sentence I'd use the first option, but if you intend to talk about the matrix 'B' in the next sentence, I'd use the latter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that I explain a general setting and then want to explain how I have realized the general idea specifically... see "Background". Another example maybe: I firstly explain that in general any approach for numerical integration could be used and then I want to add a sentence like "The Simpson rule has been applied here." Not the best example, but maybe gives an impression of the problem.

Comment: It is sufficient to state your rationale as: "The Simpson rule was applied because of ...."?  Alternatively, you could use: "In this instance/case, ...".  Again, there is nothing inherently wrong with 'here', I think it's a matter of style or preference. One other thought: have a look at other completed dissertations in your department, there must be a precedence.